# Integrate $\int_{a}^1 \frac{\left(1-t^2\right) \tanh^{-1}t }{t^6} \ln \left(\frac{t+\sqrt{-1+t^2/a^2}}{t-\sqrt{-1+t^2/a^2}}\right) dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can this integral be found in a closed-form?

$$\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^1 \frac{\left(1-t^2\right) \operatorname{arctanh}t }{t^6} \ln \left(\frac{t+\sqrt{-1+2 t^2}}{t-\sqrt{-1+2 t^2}}\right) \, \mathrm{d}t$$

A natural generalisation arises:
$$\int_{a}^1 \frac{\left(1-t^2\right) \operatorname{arctanh}t }{t^6} \ln \left(\frac{t+\sqrt{-1+t^2/a^2}}{t-\sqrt{-1+t^2/a^2}}\right) \, \mathrm{d}t$$

Comment: Numerically, the result for $a = 1/\sqrt{2}$ is $0.482562$

Comment: Where does come from this "monster"?

Comment: It is a long day

Comment: @FDP This integral arises from the theory of geometric probability theory, there are plenty of integrals in the calculation but this one was the most complicated I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Part 2.

---

Given $\left(a,b\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $0<a\le b<1$ and using the same auxiliary parameters and substitution employed for $\mathcal{F}$, the integral $\mathcal{G}$ can be rewritten as

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{G}{\left(a,b\right)}
&=\frac{b}{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\left(u-a\right)\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\left(u^{2}-b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{b}{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\left(u-a\right)\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\left(u+b\right)\left(u-b\right)\left(1+u\right)\sqrt{\frac{1-u}{1+u}}}\\
&=\frac{b}{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\int_{1}^{0}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{(-1)4A^{2}x}{\left(1+A^{2}x^{2}\right)^{2}}\cdot\frac{\left(1+B^{2}\right)^{2}\left(1+A^{2}x^{2}\right)^{2}}{2\left(1-A^{2}B^{2}x^{2}\right)\left(B^{2}-A^{2}x^{2}\right)}\\
&~~~~~\times\frac{\left(A^{2}-A^{2}x^{2}\right)}{\left(1+A^{2}\right)}\cdot\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{1-A^{4}x^{2}}{A^{2}-A^{2}x^{2}}\right)}}{\sqrt{A^{2}x^{2}}};~~~\small{\left[u=\frac{1-A^{2}x^{2}}{1+A^{2}x^{2}}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{A^{2}\left(1-B^{2}\right)\left(1+B^{2}\right)\left(1-x^{2}\right)}{\left(1-A^{2}B^{2}x^{2}\right)\left(B^{2}-A^{2}x^{2}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-A^{4}x^{2}}{A^{2}-A^{2}x^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{\left(1-A^{2}B^{2}\right)}{\left(1-A^{2}B^{2}x^{2}\right)}-\frac{\left(B^{2}-A^{2}\right)}{\left(B^{2}-A^{2}x^{2}\right)}\right]\ln{\left(\frac{1-A^{4}x^{2}}{A^{2}-A^{2}x^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{\left(1-p^{2}\right)}{\left(1-p^{2}x^{2}\right)}-\frac{\left(1-q^{2}\right)}{\left(1-q^{2}x^{2}\right)}\right]\ln{\left(\frac{1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}}{pq-pqx^{2}}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Assuming $b<a$, we have $A<B\implies q<1$, and we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{G}{\left(a,b\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{\left(1-p^{2}\right)}{\left(1-p^{2}x^{2}\right)}-\frac{\left(1-q^{2}\right)}{\left(1-q^{2}x^{2}\right)}\right]\ln{\left(\frac{1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}}{pq-pqx^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{\left(1-p^{2}\right)}{\left(1-p^{2}x^{2}\right)}-\frac{\left(1-q^{2}\right)}{\left(1-q^{2}x^{2}\right)}\right]\left[\ln{\left(1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(1-x^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(pq\right)}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(1-p^{2}\right)}{\left(1-p^{2}x^{2}\right)}\left[\ln{\left(1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(1-x^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(pq\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(1-q^{2}\right)}{\left(1-q^{2}x^{2}\right)}\left[\ln{\left(1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(1-x^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(pq\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{1-p^{2}}{2p}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2p}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}\left[\ln{\left(1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(1-x^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(pq\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\frac{1-q^{2}}{2q}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2q}{1-q^{2}x^{2}}\left[\ln{\left(1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(1-x^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(pq\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{1-p^{2}}{2p}\bigg{[}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2p\ln{\left(1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}\right)}}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2p\ln{\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}\\
&~~~~~-2\ln{\left(pq\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{p}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}\bigg{]}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{1-q^{2}}{2q}\bigg{[}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2q\ln{\left(1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}\right)}}{1-q^{2}x^{2}}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2q\ln{\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}{1-q^{2}x^{2}}\\
&~~~~~-2\ln{\left(pq\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{q}{1-q^{2}x^{2}}\bigg{]}\\
&=\frac{1-p^{2}}{2p}\bigg{[}2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-pq}{p-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+pq}{p-1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p}{p+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+pq}{p+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-pq}{p+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+1}{p-1}\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p}{p+1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-1}{p+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\ln{\left(pq\right)}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(p\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{1-q^{2}}{2q}\bigg{[}2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q}{q-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-pq}{q-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+pq}{q-1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q}{q+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+pq}{q+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-pq}{q+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q}{q-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+1}{q-1}\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q}{q+1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-1}{q+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\ln{\left(pq\right)}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(q\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=\frac{1-p^{2}}{2p}\bigg{[}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-pq}{p-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+pq}{p-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+pq}{p+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-pq}{p+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+1}{p-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-1}{p+1}\right)}-2\ln{\left(pq\right)}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(p\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{1-q^{2}}{2q}\bigg{[}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-pq}{q-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+pq}{q-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+pq}{q+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-pq}{q+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+1}{q-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-1}{q+1}\right)}-2\ln{\left(pq\right)}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(q\right)}\bigg{]}.\\
\end{align}$$

In the special case $b=a$, we have $B=A\implies q=1\land p=\frac{1-a}{1+a}$, and so

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{G}{\left(a,a\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(1-p^{2}\right)}{\left(1-p^{2}x^{2}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-p^{2}x^{2}}{p-px^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1-p^{2}}{2p}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2p}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}\left[\ln{\left(1-p^{2}x^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(1-x^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(p\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{1-p^{2}}{2p}\left[\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2p\ln{\left(1-p^{2}x^{2}\right)}}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2p\ln{\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2p\ln{\left(p\right)}}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}\right]\\
&=\frac{1-p^{2}}{2p}\bigg{[}2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{2p}{p-1}\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p}{p+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{2p}{p+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+1}{p-1}\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p}{p+1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-1}{p+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\ln{\left(p\right)}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(p\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=\frac{1-p^{2}}{2p}\bigg{[}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{2p}{p-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{2p}{p+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+1}{p-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-1}{p+1}\right)}+\ln{\left(\frac{1-p}{1+p}\right)}\ln{\left(p\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=\frac{2a}{1-a^{2}}\bigg{[}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{a-1}{a}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-\frac{1}{a}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-a\right)}+\ln{\left(a\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=\frac{2a}{1-a^{2}}\bigg{[}2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1-a\right)}+\frac12\ln^{2}{\left(a\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-a\right)}-\frac12\ln^{2}{\left(a\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\ln{\left(a\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=\frac{2a}{1-a^{2}}\bigg{[}2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}-2\ln{\left(a\right)}\ln{\left(1-a\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-a\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\ln{\left(a\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=\frac{2a}{1-a^{2}}\bigg{[}2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-a\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\ln{\left(a\right)}\left[2\ln{\left(1-a\right)}+\ln{\left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)}\right]\bigg{]}\\
&=\frac{2a}{1-a^{2}}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}-\ln{\left(a\right)}\ln{\left(1-a^{2}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a^{2}\right)}\right].\\
\end{align}$$

---

Given $\left(a,b\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $0<a\le b<1$ and again reusing the auxiliary parameters and initial substitution employed for $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$, the integral $\mathcal{H}$ can be rewritten as

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}{\left(a,b\right)}
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\sqrt{1-b^{2}}\,u\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{2a}\right)}}{\left(u^{2}-b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\left(1+b\right)\sqrt{\frac{1-b}{1+b}}\,u\left[\ln{\left(u+a\right)}-\ln{\left(2\right)}-\ln{\left(a\right)}\right]}{\left(u+b\right)\left(u-b\right)\left(1+u\right)\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}\sqrt{\frac{(1+a)(1-u)}{(1-a)(1+u)}}}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1-A^{2}}{1+A^{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\left(1+\frac{1-B^{2}}{1+B^{2}}\right)Bu\left[\ln{\left(u+\frac{1-A^{2}}{1+A^{2}}\right)}-\ln{\left(2\right)}-\ln{\left(\frac{1-A^{2}}{1+A^{2}}\right)}\right]}{\left(u+\frac{1-B^{2}}{1+B^{2}}\right)\left(u-\frac{1-B^{2}}{1+B^{2}}\right)\left(1+u\right)A\sqrt{\frac{1-u}{A^{2}(1+u)}}}\\
&=\int_{1}^{0}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{(-1)4A^{2}x}{\left(1+A^{2}x^{2}\right)^{2}}\cdot\frac{2\left(1+\frac{1-B^{2}}{1+B^{2}}\right)B\left(\frac{1-A^{2}x^{2}}{1+A^{2}x^{2}}\right)}{\left(\frac{1-A^{2}x^{2}}{1+A^{2}x^{2}}+\frac{1-B^{2}}{1+B^{2}}\right)\left(\frac{1-A^{2}x^{2}}{1+A^{2}x^{2}}-\frac{1-B^{2}}{1+B^{2}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1-A^{2}x^{2}}{1+A^{2}x^{2}}\right)A\sqrt{x^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~\times\left[\ln{\left(\frac{1-A^{2}x^{2}}{1+A^{2}x^{2}}+\frac{1-A^{2}}{1+A^{2}}\right)}-\ln{\left(2\right)}-\ln{\left(\frac{1-A^{2}}{1+A^{2}}\right)}\right];~~~\small{\left[u=\frac{1-A^{2}x^{2}}{1+A^{2}x^{2}}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2AB\left(1+B^{2}\right)\left(1-A^{2}x^{2}\right)}{\left(1-A^{2}B^{2}x^{2}\right)\left(B^{2}-A^{2}x^{2}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-A^{4}x^{2}}{\left(1-A^{2}\right)\left(1+A^{2}x^{2}\right)}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2\left(p+q\right)\left(1-pqx^{2}\right)}{\left(1-p^{2}x^{2}\right)\left(1-q^{2}x^{2}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}}{\left(1-pq\right)\left(1+pqx^{2}\right)}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{2p}{\left(1-p^{2}x^{2}\right)}+\frac{2q}{\left(1-q^{2}x^{2}\right)}\right]\ln{\left(\frac{1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}}{\left(1-pq\right)\left(1+pqx^{2}\right)}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Set $\beta:=2\arctan{\left(B\right)}$. Then, $0<\beta<\frac{\pi}{2}\land B=\tan{\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)}\land\frac{q-p}{p+q}=\frac{1-B^{2}}{1+B^{2}}=\cos{\left(\beta\right)}$.

Also, set $r:=\frac{1-p}{1+p}\land s:=\frac{1-q}{1+q}$. Then, $0\le s<r<1$ with $s=0\iff q=1$, and we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}{\left(a,b\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{2p}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}+\frac{2q}{1-q^{2}x^{2}}\right]\ln{\left(\frac{1}{1-pq}\cdot\frac{1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}}{1+pqx^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2p}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{1}{1-pq}\cdot\frac{1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}}{1+pqx^{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2q}{1-q^{2}x^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{1}{1-pq}\cdot\frac{1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}}{1+pqx^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{p}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2}{1-y^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{p}{1-pq}\cdot\frac{1-q^{2}y^{2}}{p+qy^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[x=p^{-1}y\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{q}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{2}{1-y^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{q}{1-pq}\cdot\frac{1-p^{2}y^{2}}{q+py^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[x=q^{-1}y\right]}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1-p}{1+p}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{p}{1-pq}\cdot\frac{1-q^{2}\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^{2}}{p+q\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{\frac{1-q}{1+q}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{q}{1-pq}\cdot\frac{1-p^{2}\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^{2}}{q+p\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[y=\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right]}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1-p}{1+p}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{p}{1-pq}\cdot\frac{\left(1+t\right)^{2}-q^{2}\left(1-t\right)^{2}}{p\left(1+t\right)^{2}+q\left(1-t\right)^{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{\frac{1-q}{1+q}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{q}{1-pq}\cdot\frac{\left(1+t\right)^{2}-p^{2}\left(1-t\right)^{2}}{q\left(1+t\right)^{2}+p\left(1-t\right)^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1-p}{1+p}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{p}{1-pq}\cdot\frac{\left[\left(1+t\right)-q\left(1-t\right)\right]\left[\left(1+t\right)+q\left(1-t\right)\right]}{p\left(1+2t+t^{2}\right)+q\left(1-2t+t^{2}\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{\frac{1-q}{1+q}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{q}{1-pq}\cdot\frac{\left[\left(1+t\right)-p\left(1-t\right)\right]\left[\left(1+t\right)+p\left(1-t\right)\right]}{q\left(1+2t+t^{2}\right)+p\left(1-2t+t^{2}\right)}\right)}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1-p}{1+p}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{p}{1-pq}\cdot\frac{\left[\left(1-q\right)+\left(1+q\right)t\right]\left[\left(1+q\right)+\left(1-q\right)t\right]}{\left(p+q\right)-2\left(q-p\right)t+\left(p+q\right)t^{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{\frac{1-q}{1+q}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{q}{1-pq}\cdot\frac{\left[\left(1-p\right)+\left(1+p\right)t\right]\left[\left(1+p\right)+\left(1-p\right)t\right]}{\left(p+q\right)+2\left(q-p\right)t+\left(p+q\right)t^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{\frac{1-p}{1+p}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{p\left(1+q\right)^{2}\left[\left(\frac{1-q}{1+q}\right)+t\right]\left[1+\left(\frac{1-q}{1+q}\right)t\right]}{\left(1-pq\right)\left(p+q\right)\left[1-2\left(\frac{q-p}{p+q}\right)t+t^{2}\right]}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{\frac{1-q}{1+q}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{q\left(1+p\right)^{2}\left[\left(\frac{1-p}{1+p}\right)+t\right]\left[1+\left(\frac{1-p}{1+p}\right)t\right]}{\left(1-pq\right)\left(p+q\right)\left[1+2\left(\frac{q-p}{p+q}\right)t+t^{2}\right]}\right)}\\
&=\int_{r}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)\left(s+t\right)\left(1+st\right)}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)\left[1-2t\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+t^{2}\right]}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{s}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-s^{2}\right)\left(r+t\right)\left(1+rt\right)}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)\left[1+2t\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+t^{2}\right]}\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

and then,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}{\left(a,b\right)}
&=\int_{r}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)\left(s+t\right)\left(1+st\right)}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)\left[1-2t\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+t^{2}\right]}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{s}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-s^{2}\right)\left(r+t\right)\left(1+rt\right)}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)\left[1+2t\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+t^{2}\right]}\right)}\\
&=\int_{r}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)\left(s+t\right)}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}+\int_{r}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+st\right)}}{t}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{r}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-2t\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+t^{2}\right)}}{t}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{s}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-s^{2}\right)\left(r+t\right)}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}+\int_{s}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{t}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{s}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+2t\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+t^{2}\right)}}{t}\\
&=\int_{r}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)\left(s+t\right)}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+st\right)}}{t}-\int_{0}^{r}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+st\right)}}{t}\\
&~~~~~-2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-2t\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+t^{2}\right)}}{2t}+2\int_{0}^{r}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-2t\cos{\left(\beta\right)}+t^{2}\right)}}{2t}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{s}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-s^{2}\right)\left(r+t\right)}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{t}-\int_{0}^{s}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+rt\right)}}{t}\\
&~~~~~-2\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-2t\cos{\left(\pi-\beta\right)}+t^{2}\right)}}{2t}+2\int_{0}^{s}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-2t\cos{\left(\pi-\beta\right)}+t^{2}\right)}}{2t}\\
&=\int_{r}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)\left(s+t\right)}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-s\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-rs\right)}\\
&~~~~~+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\beta\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{s}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-s^{2}\right)\left(r+t\right)}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-r\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-rs\right)}\\
&~~~~~+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\pi-\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(s,\pi-\beta\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

For $b<a$, we have $A<B\implies q<1\implies 0<s$, and then

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}{\left(a,b\right)}
&=\int_{r}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)\left(s+t\right)}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-s\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-rs\right)}\\
&~~~~~+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\beta\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{s}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-s^{2}\right)\left(r+t\right)}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-r\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-rs\right)}\\
&~~~~~+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\pi-\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(s,\pi-\beta\right)}\\
&=\int_{r}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)s}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}+\int_{r}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+s^{-1}t\right)}}{t}\\
&~~~~~-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-s\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-rs\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\beta\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{s}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-s^{2}\right)r}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}+\int_{s}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(1+r^{-1}t\right)}}{t}\\
&~~~~~-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-r\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-rs\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\pi-\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(s,\pi-\beta\right)}\\
&=-\ln{\left(r\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)s}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-s^{-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-rs^{-1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-s\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-rs\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\beta\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\ln{\left(s\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-s^{2}\right)r}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-r^{-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-sr^{-1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-r\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-rs\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\pi-\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(s,\pi-\beta\right)}\\
&=-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\frac12\ln^{2}{\left(r\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\frac12\ln^{2}{\left(s\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}-\frac12\ln^{2}{\left(\frac{r}{s}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\ln{\left(r\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)s}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}-\ln{\left(s\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-s^{2}\right)r}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-rs\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\left(\pi-\beta\right)^{2}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\frac12\beta^{2}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(s,\pi-\beta\right)}\\
&=2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}+\ln{\left(r\right)}\ln{\left(s\right)}-\ln{\left(r\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)s}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}-\ln{\left(s\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-s^{2}\right)r}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\pi^{2}}{2}-\pi\beta+\beta^{2}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-rs\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(s,\pi-\beta\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{2}}{3}-\ln{\left(r\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)s}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}-\ln{\left(s\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-s^{2}\right)r}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\ln{\left(r\right)}\ln{\left(s\right)}-\beta\left(\pi-\beta\right)+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-rs\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(s,\pi-\beta\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

In the special case $b=a\implies B=A\implies q=1\implies s=0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}{\left(a,a\right)}
&=\int_{r}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)t}{r}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(0\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(0\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\beta\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{r+t}{r}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-r\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(0\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\pi-\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(0,\pi-\beta\right)}\\
&=\int_{r}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{t}\ln{\left(\frac{1-r^{2}}{r}\right)}+\int_{r}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\ln{\left(t\right)}}{t}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\beta\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-r^{-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-r\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\pi-\beta\right)}\\
&=-\ln{\left(r\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-r^{2}}{r}\right)}-\frac12\ln^{2}{\left(r\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\beta\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-r^{-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-r\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1,\pi-\beta\right)}\\
&=2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}-\ln{\left(r\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-r^{2}}{r}\right)}+\frac12\beta^{2}+\frac12\left(\pi-\beta\right)^{2}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\beta\right)}\\
&=2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}-\ln{\left(\frac{1-p}{1+p}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{4p}{1-p^{2}}\right)}+\frac12\beta^{2}+\frac12\left(\pi-\beta\right)^{2}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{1-p}{1+p},\beta\right)}\\
&=2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}-\ln{\left(\frac{1-A^{2}}{1+A^{2}}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{4A^{2}}{1-A^{4}}\right)}+\frac12\beta^{2}+\frac12\left(\pi-\beta\right)^{2}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{1-B^{2}}{1+B^{2}},\beta\right)}\\
&=2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}-\ln{\left(a\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-a^{2}}{a}\right)}+\frac12\beta^{2}+\frac12\left(\pi-\beta\right)^{2}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\cos{\left(\beta\right)},\beta\right)}\\
&=2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-1\right)}-\ln{\left(a\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-a^{2}}{a}\right)}+\frac12\beta^{2}+\frac12\left(\pi-\beta\right)^{2}-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\beta\right)^{2}-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\cos^{2}{\left(\beta\right)}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}-\ln{\left(a\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-a^{2}}{a}\right)}-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a^{2}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Putting everything together, for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\le a<1$ with $b=\sqrt{1-a^{2}}$ we obtain the following nightmarish result:

$$\begin{align}
60a^{4}\mathcal{I}{\left(a\right)}
&=\mathcal{E}{\left(a,b\right)}+\mathcal{F}{\left(a,b\right)}+4a^{5}\mathcal{G}{\left(a,b\right)}-8a^{4}\mathcal{H}{\left(a,b\right)}\\
&=2a\left(2-3a^{2}+3b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-a^{2}}+\frac{2a\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+12\mathcal{J}_{4}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)\mathcal{J}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)b^{2}\mathcal{J}_{0}{\left(a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(2a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}-3b^{4}\right)}{b\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}\bigg{[}-2\ln{\left(pq\right)}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(\frac{q-p}{1-pq}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+1}{p-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-1}{p+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+1}{q-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-1}{q+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-pq}{p-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+pq}{p-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+pq}{p+1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-pq}{p+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-pq}{q-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+pq}{q-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+pq}{q+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-pq}{q+1}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{4a^{5}(1-p^{2})}{2p}\bigg{[}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-pq}{p-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+pq}{p-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+pq}{p+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-pq}{p+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+1}{p-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-1}{p+1}\right)}-2\ln{\left(pq\right)}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(p\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{4a^{5}(1-q^{2})}{2q}\bigg{[}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-pq}{q-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+pq}{q-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+pq}{q+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-pq}{q+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+1}{q-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-1}{q+1}\right)}-2\ln{\left(pq\right)}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(q\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&~~~~~-8a^{4}\bigg{[}2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}-\ln{\left(r\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-r^{2}\right)s}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}-\ln{\left(s\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{\left(1-s^{2}\right)r}{\left(r+s\right)\left(1-rs\right)}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\ln{\left(r\right)}\ln{\left(s\right)}-\beta\left(\pi-\beta\right)+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(-rs\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\beta\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(s,\pi-\beta\right)}\bigg{]}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Finally, we obtain an explicit value for the integral in the $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ special case. Considering how cumbersome the general case turned out to be, the final result is very pleasingly concise!

$$\begin{align}
15\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}
&=\mathcal{E}{\left(a,a\right)}+\mathcal{F}{\left(a,a\right)}+4a^{5}\mathcal{G}{\left(a,a\right)}-8a^{4}\mathcal{H}{\left(a,a\right)}\\
&=4a\sqrt{1-a^{2}}+12\mathcal{J}_{4}{\left(a\right)}-8a^{2}\mathcal{J}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-8a^{4}\mathcal{J}_{0}{\left(a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+4a^{5}\left(\frac{2a}{1-a^{2}}\right)\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}-\ln{\left(a\right)}\ln{\left(1-a^{2}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a^{2}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-8a^{4}\left[\frac12\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}-\ln{\left(a\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-a^{2}}{a}\right)}-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a^{2}\right)}\right]\\
&=11a\sqrt{1-a^{2}}+\left(9-2a^{2}\right)a\sqrt{1-a^{2}}\ln{\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac12\left(9-8a^{2}-16a^{4}\right)\left[\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(2\arccos{\left(a\right)}\right)}+\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\pi-2\arccos{\left(a\right)}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac{8a^{6}}{1-a^{2}}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}-\ln{\left(a\right)}\ln{\left(1-a^{2}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a^{2}\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-4a^{4}\left[\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}-2\ln{\left(a\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-a^{2}}{a}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(a^{2}\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{11}{2}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(1\right)}-\frac12\ln^{2}{\left(2\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac12\right)}+\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{11}{2}+\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}+C,\\
\end{align}$$

where here $C$ denotes the Catalan constant.

---

Whew! If you made it here to the bottom, do like me and go take a well deserved nap. Cheers :p

Comment: This result is truly hilarious! The integral originated from the problem of mean values in geometric probability I was interested back then (example: find mean area of triangle created from three points randomly selected from a cube of unite volume). I am not sure which problem was it as I was interested in a lot of them, nor whether there were other integrals to be solved, I need to trace back almost three years ago to find out. But in case your result is indeed the key to one of the problems, I need to ask whether you would be interested in writing a joint paper on that problem.

Comment: I found it! The integral is related to probability that random triangle picked from the interior of a unit cube is obtuse. See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeTrianglePicking.html . Numerically, this is equal to 0.542659.... In the precise computation, however, there are, unfortunately, dozens of similar integrals (it would then take weeks to find the exact values of all of them). However, this one appeared to be the hardest. Therefore, using your result, it seems that the overall probability can be expressed in exact form after all!

Answer (score 4):

### Part 1.

Warning: Incoming Wall of Math. I ended up having to split this answer into two parts because it ended up exceeding the character limit.

---

Recalling the integral definition of the inverse hyperbolic tangent, as well as its logarithmic form,

$$\operatorname{artanh}{\left(z\right)}:=\int_{0}^{z}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{1-t^{2}}=\frac12\ln{\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)};~~~\small{-1<z<1},$$

define the function $\mathcal{I}:\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ via the definite integral

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(a\right)}:=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}}{t^{6}}\ln{\left(\frac{t+\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}{t-\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\right)}.$$

(Note: The domain of $\mathcal{I}$ has been inferred by requiring the defining integral's integrand be real-valued.)

It can be shown that for all $(a,t)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\le a<1\land a\le t\le1\land\neg\left(a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\land t=1\right)$, the following inequalities hold:

$$t-\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}>0,$$

$$\frac{t+\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}{t-\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\ge1.$$

Using L'Hôpital's rule, it can be shown that

$$\lim_{t\to1^{-}}\left(1-t\right)\ln{\left(1-t\right)}=0,$$

$$\lim_{t\to1^{-}}\left(1-t\right)\ln^{2}{\left(1-t\right)}=0,$$

and so

$$\lim_{t\to1^{-}}\left(1-t^{2}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}=0,$$

$$\lim_{t\to1^{-}}\frac{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}}{t^{6}}\ln{\left(\frac{t+\sqrt{2t^{2}-1}}{t-\sqrt{2t^{2}-1}}\right)}=0,$$

As such, the singularities of the integrand of $\mathcal{I}$ are removable and do not lead to improper integrals.

Our goal is to obtain a general closed-form expression for $\mathcal{I}$ in terms of elementary functions, dilogarithms, and related functions such as the Clausen function and the following two-variable variant of the dilogarithm:

$$\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(r,\theta\right)}:=-\frac12\int_{0}^{r}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\ln{\left(1-2x\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+x^{2}\right)}}{x};~~~\small{\left(r,\theta\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}},$$

We are particularly interested in the special case,

$$\mathcal{I}{\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}=\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}}{t^{6}}\ln{\left(\frac{t+\sqrt{2t^{2}-1}}{t-\sqrt{2t^{2}-1}}\right)}\approx0.482562.$$

---

Suppose $a\in\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\right)$. Calculating the derivative of the logarithmic expression $\ln{\left(\frac{t+\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}{t-\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\right)}$ w.r.t. $t$, we obtain the following: for $t\in(a,1)$,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\ln{\left(\frac{t+\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}{t-\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\right)}
&=\left(\frac{t+\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}{t-\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\right)^{-1}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{t+\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}{t-\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\right)\\
&=\frac{t-\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}{t+\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\cdot\frac{2}{\left(t-\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}\right)^{2}\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\\
&=\frac{2}{\left(t-\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}\right)\left(t+\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}\right)\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\\
&=\frac{2}{\left[t^{2}-\left(\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1\right)\right]\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\\
&=\frac{2}{\left[1-\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}}-1\right)t^{2}\right]\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Since $\ln{\left(\frac{t+\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}{t-\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\right)}=0$ at $t=a$ for any $a\in\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\right)$, it follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus that

$$\int_{a}^{t}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{\left[1-\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}}-1\right)x^{2}\right]\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}=\ln{\left(\frac{t+\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}{t-\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\right)};~~~\small{\neg\left(a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\land t=1\right)}.$$

We can use this integral representation to rewrite $\mathcal{I}$ as a double integral and try to evaluate $\mathcal{I}$ by changing the order of integration. For any $a\in\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\right)$,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}{\left(a\right)}
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}}{t^{6}}\ln{\left(\frac{t+\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}{t-\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\right)}\\
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}}{t^{6}}\int_{a}^{t}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{\left[1-\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}}-1\right)x^{2}\right]\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\\
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{a}^{t}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{\left[1-\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}}-1\right)x^{2}\right]\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\cdot\frac{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}}{t^{6}}\\
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2}{\left[1-\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}}-1\right)x^{2}\right]\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\cdot\frac{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}}{t^{6}}\\
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{\left[1-\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}}-1\right)x^{2}\right]\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}}{t^{6}}\\
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{\left[1-\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}}-1\right)x^{2}\right]\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}f{\left(x\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

where in the last line above we've introduced the auxiliary function $f:(0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$f{\left(x\right)}:=\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}}{t^{6}}.$$

For $x\in(0,1)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
f{\left(x\right)}
&=\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(1-t^{2}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}}{t^{6}}\\
&=\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(\frac{1}{t^{6}}-\frac{1}{t^{4}}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}\\
&=\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{d}{dt}\left[-\frac{1}{5t^{5}}+\frac{1}{3t^{3}}-\frac{2}{15}\right]\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}\\
&=\lim_{t\to1^{-}}\left[\left(-\frac{1}{5t^{5}}+\frac{1}{3t^{3}}-\frac{2}{15}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}\right]-\lim_{t\to x}\left[\left(-\frac{1}{5t^{5}}+\frac{1}{3t^{3}}-\frac{2}{15}\right)\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(-\frac{1}{5t^{5}}+\frac{1}{3t^{3}}-\frac{2}{15}\right)\frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}\\
&=-\lim_{t\to1^{-}}\left[\frac{3-5t^{2}+2t^{5}}{15t^{5}}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}\right]+\frac{3-5x^{2}+2x^{5}}{15x^{5}}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(x\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{3-5t^{2}+2t^{5}}{15t^{5}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-t^{2}}\\
&=-\lim_{t\to1^{-}}\left[\frac{\left(3+6t+4t^{2}+2t^{3}\right)\left(1-t\right)^{2}}{15t^{5}}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(t\right)}\right]+\frac{3-5x^{2}+2x^{5}}{15x^{5}}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(x\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(3+6t+4t^{2}+2t^{3}\right)\left(1-t\right)^{2}}{15t^{5}\left(1-t^{2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{3-5x^{2}+2x^{5}}{15x^{5}}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(x\right)}+\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{\left(3+6t+4t^{2}+2t^{3}\right)\left(1-t\right)}{15t^{5}\left(1+t\right)}\\
&=\frac{3-5x^{2}+2x^{5}}{15x^{5}}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{15}\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\left(\frac{3}{t^{5}}-\frac{2}{t^{3}}-\frac{2}{t}+\frac{2}{1+t}\right)\\
&=\frac{3-5x^{2}+2x^{5}}{15x^{5}}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{15}\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{d}{dt}\left[-\frac{3}{4t^{4}}+\frac{1}{t^{2}}-2\ln{(t)}+2\ln{(1+t)}\right]\\
&=\frac{3-5x^{2}+2x^{5}}{15x^{5}}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{15}\left[\frac14+2\ln{(2)}+\frac{3}{4x^{4}}-\frac{1}{x^{2}}+2\ln{(x)}-2\ln{(1+x)}\right]\\
&=\frac{2\left(3-5x^{2}+2x^{5}\right)}{60x^{5}}\ln{\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}+\frac{1}{60}\left[\frac{3}{x^{4}}-\frac{4}{x^{2}}+1+8\ln{\left(\frac{2x}{1+x}\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{60}\bigg{[}\frac{3}{x^{4}}-\frac{4}{x^{2}}+1+2\left(\frac{3}{x^{5}}-\frac{5}{x^{3}}+2\right)\ln{\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}-8\ln{\left(\frac{1+x}{2x}\right)}\bigg{]}.\\
\end{align}$$

Then, given $a\in\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},1\right)$, we find

$$\begin{align}
60a^{4}\mathcal{I}{\left(a\right)}
&=60a^{4}\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{\left[1-\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}}-1\right)x^{2}\right]\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}f{\left(x\right)}\\
&=60a^{4}\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2}{\left[1-\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}}-1\right)x^{2}\right]\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\cdot\frac{1}{60}\bigg{[}\frac{3}{x^{4}}-\frac{4}{x^{2}}+1\\
&~~~~~+2\left(\frac{3}{x^{5}}-\frac{5}{x^{3}}+2\right)\ln{\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}-8\ln{\left(\frac{1+x}{2x}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2a^{4}}{\left[1-\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}}-1\right)x^{2}\right]\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}-1}}\bigg{[}\frac{3}{x^{4}}-\frac{4}{x^{2}}+1\\
&~~~~~+2\left(\frac{3}{x^{5}}-\frac{5}{x^{3}}+2\right)\ln{\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}-8\ln{\left(\frac{1+x}{2x}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=\int_{a^{-1}}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{(-1)}{t^{2}}\cdot\frac{2a^{4}}{\left[1-\left(a^{-2}-1\right)t^{-2}\right]\sqrt{a^{-2}t^{-2}-1}}\bigg{[}3t^{4}-4t^{2}+1\\
&~~~~~+2\left(3t^{5}-5t^{3}+2\right)\ln{\left(\frac{t+1}{t-1}\right)}-8\ln{\left(\frac{t+1}{2}\right)}\bigg{]};~~~\small{\left[x=\frac{1}{t}\right]}\\
&=\int_{1}^{a^{-1}}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{2a^{7}t}{\left[a^{2}t^{2}-\left(1-a^{2}\right)\right]\sqrt{1-a^{2}t^{2}}}\bigg{[}3t^{4}-4t^{2}+1\\
&~~~~~+2\left(3t^{5}-5t^{3}+2\right)\ln{\left(\frac{t+1}{t-1}\right)}-8\ln{\left(\frac{t+1}{2}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2u}{\left[u^{2}-\left(1-a^{2}\right)\right]\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\bigg{[}a\left(3u^{4}-4a^{2}u^{2}+a^{4}\right)\\
&~~~~~+2\left(3u^{5}-5a^{2}u^{3}+2a^{5}\right)\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}-8a^{5}\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{2a}\right)}\bigg{]};~~~\small{\left[t=a^{-1}u\right]}\\
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2au\left(3u^{4}-4a^{2}u^{2}+a^{4}\right)}{\left[u^{2}-\left(1-a^{2}\right)\right]\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}+4\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u\left(3u^{5}-5a^{2}u^{3}+2a^{5}\right)\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\left[u^{2}-\left(1-a^{2}\right)\right]\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~-8a^{4}\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2au\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{2a}\right)}}{\left[u^{2}-\left(1-a^{2}\right)\right]\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2au\left(3u^{4}-4a^{2}u^{2}+a^{4}\right)}{\left[u^{2}-\left(1-a^{2}\right)\right]\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}+4\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\left(3u^{6}-5a^{2}u^{4}+2a^{6}\right)\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\left[u^{2}-\left(1-a^{2}\right)\right]\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~+4a^{5}\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\left(u-a\right)\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\left[u^{2}-\left(1-a^{2}\right)\right]\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}-8a^{4}\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2au\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{2a}\right)}}{\left[u^{2}-\left(1-a^{2}\right)\right]\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2au\left(3u^{4}-4a^{2}u^{2}+a^{4}\right)}{\left(u^{2}-b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}+\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{4\left(3u^{6}-5a^{2}u^{4}+2a^{6}\right)\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\left(u^{2}-b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{4a^{5}b}{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\left(u-a\right)\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\left(u^{2}-b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}-8a^{4}\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\sqrt{1-b^{2}}\,u\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{2a}\right)}}{\left(u^{2}-b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}},\\
\end{align}$$

where in the last line above we've set $b:=\sqrt{1-a^{2}}$. Then, $a=\sqrt{1-b^{2}}$ and

$$0<b\le a<1\land\left(b=a\iff a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$

Introduce the auxiliary functions $\mathcal{E},\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H}$ given by the respective definite integrals:

$$\mathcal{E}{\left(a,b\right)}:=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2au\left(3u^{4}-4a^{2}u^{2}+a^{4}\right)}{\left(u^{2}-b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}};~~~\small{0<b\le a<1},$$

$$\mathcal{F}{\left(a,b\right)}:=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{4\left(3u^{6}-5a^{2}u^{4}+2a^{6}\right)\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\left(u^{2}-b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}};~~~\small{0<b\le a<1},$$

$$\mathcal{G}{\left(a,b\right)}:=\frac{b}{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\left(u-a\right)\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\left(u^{2}-b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}};~~~\small{0<b\le a<1},$$

$$\mathcal{H}{\left(a,b\right)}:=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2\sqrt{1-b^{2}}\,u\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{2a}\right)}}{\left(u^{2}-b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}};~~~\small{0<b\le a<1}.$$

We can then express the integral $\mathcal{I}$ as

$$\begin{align}
60a^{4}\mathcal{I}{\left(a\right)}
&=\mathcal{E}{\left(a,\sqrt{1-a^{2}}\right)}+\mathcal{F}{\left(a,\sqrt{1-a^{2}}\right)}+4a^{5}\mathcal{G}{\left(a,\sqrt{1-a^{2}}\right)}-8a^{4}\mathcal{H}{\left(a,\sqrt{1-a^{2}}\right)}\\
&=\mathcal{E}{\left(a,b\right)}+\mathcal{F}{\left(a,b\right)}+4a^{5}\mathcal{G}{\left(a,b\right)}-8a^{4}\mathcal{H}{\left(a,b\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

We begin with the evaluation of $\mathcal{E}$, which we can tell at a glance is elementary. For $0<b\le a<1$,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}{\left(a,b\right)}
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{2au\left(3u^{4}-4a^{2}u^{2}+a^{4}\right)}{\left(u^{2}-b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\left[3u^{2}-\left(4a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)+\frac{\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)}{u^{2}-b^{2}}\right]\frac{2au}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=2a\int_{1}^{a}\mathrm{d}u\,\left[-\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\right]\left[3u^{2}-\left(4a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)+\frac{\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)}{u^{2}-b^{2}}\right]\\
&=2a\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[3\left(1-x^{2}\right)-\left(4a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)+\frac{\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)}{1-x^{2}-b^{2}}\right];~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{1-u^{2}}=x\right]}\\
&=2a\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\left(3-4a^{2}+3b^{2}\right)-3x^{2}+\frac{\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)}{1-b^{2}-x^{2}}\right].\\
\end{align}$$

In the special case $b=a$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}{\left(a,a\right)}
&=2a\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\left(3-a^{2}\right)-3x^{2}\right]\\
&=2a\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{d}{dx}\left[\left(3-a^{2}\right)x-x^{3}\right]\\
&=2a\left[\left(3-a^{2}\right)-\left(1-a^{2}\right)\right]\sqrt{1-a^{2}}\\
&=4a\sqrt{1-a^{2}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Assuming $b<a$, we find

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}{\left(a,b\right)}
&=2a\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\left(3-4a^{2}+3b^{2}\right)-3x^{2}+\frac{\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)}{1-b^{2}-x^{2}}\right]\\
&=2a\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}}\mathrm{d}y\,\sqrt{1-b^{2}}\bigg{[}\left(3-4a^{2}+3b^{2}\right)-3\left(1-b^{2}\right)y^{2}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)}{1-b^{2}-\left(1-b^{2}\right)y^{2}}\bigg{]};~~~\small{\left[x=\sqrt{1-b^{2}}\,y\right]}\\
&=2a\sqrt{1-b^{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}}\mathrm{d}y\,\bigg{[}\left(3-4a^{2}+3b^{2}\right)-3\left(1-b^{2}\right)y^{2}+\frac{\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)}{\left(1-b^{2}\right)\left(1-y^{2}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=2a\sqrt{1-b^{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{d}{dy}\bigg{[}\left(3-4a^{2}+3b^{2}\right)y-\left(1-b^{2}\right)y^{3}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)}{\left(1-b^{2}\right)}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(y\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=2a\sqrt{1-b^{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{d}{dy}\bigg{[}\left((3-4a^{2}+3b^{2})-(1-b^{2})y^{2}\right)y\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)}{\left(1-b^{2}\right)}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(y\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=2a\sqrt{1-b^{2}}\bigg{[}\left((3-4a^{2}+3b^{2})-(1-b^{2})\frac{1-a^{2}}{1-b^{2}}\right)\frac{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)}{\left(1-b^{2}\right)}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=2a\left(2-3a^{2}+3b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-a^{2}}+\frac{2a\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-a^{2}}}{\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

The following auxiliary function (discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4674091/)) will be helpful in the evaluation of $\mathcal{F}$:

$$\mathcal{J}_{n}{\left(a\right)}:=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u^{n}\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}};~~~\small{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}\land a\in(0,1)}.$$

Given $a\in(0,1)$, it can be shown that

$$\mathcal{J}_{0}{\left(a\right)}=\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(2\alpha\right)}+\operatorname{Cl}_{2}{\left(\pi-2\alpha\right)};~~~\small{\alpha=2\arctan{\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}\right)}},$$

$$\mathcal{J}_{1}{\left(a\right)}=-\sqrt{1-a^{2}}\ln{\left(1-a^{2}\right)}+4a\arctan{\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}\right)}.$$

Also, the following recurrence relation holds for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}\land a\in(0,1)$:

$$(n+2)\mathcal{J}_{n+2}{\left(a\right)}=(n+1)\mathcal{J}_{n}{\left(a\right)}+a^{n+1}\mathcal{J}_{1}{\left(a\right)}-2a\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}u^{n-k}a^{k}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}{u+a}.$$

---

The following integration formula will be helpful in parts of the evaluation of $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{a\ln{\left(1-bx\right)}}{1-ax}=\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(b\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{a}{a-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{a-b}{a-1}\right)};~~~\small{a<1\land b\le1}.$$

It follows that for $-1<a<1\land-1\le b\le1$ we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2a\ln{\left(1-b^{2}x^{2}\right)}}{1-a^{2}x^{2}}
&=2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{a}{a-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{a-b}{a-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{a+b}{a-1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{a}{a+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{a+b}{a+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{a-b}{a+1}\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Suppose $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\land0<b\le a<1$. Then, $0<\frac{1-a}{1+a}\le\frac{1-b}{1+b}<1$. Setting

$$A:=\sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}\land B:=\sqrt{\frac{1-b}{1+b}},$$

we have $0<A\le B<1$ with $B=A\iff b=a$, and $a=\frac{1-A^{2}}{1+A^{2}}\land b=\frac{1-B^{2}}{1+B^{2}}$. Next, set

$$p:=AB\land q:=\frac{A}{B}.$$

Then, $0<p<q\le1$ with $q=1\iff B=A$, and $A=\sqrt{pq}\land B=\sqrt{\frac{p}{q}}$.

We will make use of the following substitution to evaluate $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H}$:

$$\sqrt{\frac{(1+a)(1-u)}{(1-a)(1+u)}}=x,$$

$$\implies\frac{1-u}{1+u}=\left(\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right)x^{2}=A^{2}x^{2},$$

$$\implies u=\frac{1-A^{2}x^{2}}{1+A^{2}x^{2}},$$

$$\implies du=dx\,\frac{(-1)4A^{2}x}{\left(1+A^{2}x^{2}\right)^{2}}.$$

---

Consider the following partial fraction decomposition, which is straightforward to verify:

$$\frac{3u^{6}-5a^{2}u^{4}+2a^{6}}{u^{2}-b^{2}}=3u^{4}-\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)u^{2}-\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)b^{2}+\frac{\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(2a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}-3b^{4}\right)}{u^{2}-b^{2}}.$$

Then, for $\left(a,b\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $0<b<a<1$, we find $\mathcal{F}$ can be rewritten as

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}{\left(a,b\right)}
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{4\left(3u^{6}-5a^{2}u^{4}+2a^{6}\right)\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\left(u^{2}-b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\bigg{[}3u^{4}-\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)u^{2}-\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)b^{2}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(2a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}-3b^{4}\right)}{u^{2}-b^{2}}\bigg{]}\frac{4\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=12\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u^{4}\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{u^{2}\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)b^{2}\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&~~~~~+\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(2a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}-3b^{4}\right)\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{4\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\left(u^{2}-b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=12\mathcal{J}_{4}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)\mathcal{J}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)b^{2}\mathcal{J}_{0}{\left(a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(2a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}-3b^{4}\right)\int_{a}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{4\ln{\left(\frac{u+a}{u-a}\right)}}{\left(u^{2}-b^{2}\right)\sqrt{1-u^{2}}}\\
&=12\mathcal{J}_{4}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)\mathcal{J}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)b^{2}\mathcal{J}_{0}{\left(a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(2a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}-3b^{4}\right)\int_{1}^{0}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{(-1)4A^{2}x}{\left(1+A^{2}x^{2}\right)^{2}}\cdot\frac{\left(1+B^{2}\right)\left(1+A^{2}x^{2}\right)}{\left(1-A^{2}B^{2}x^{2}\right)}\\
&~~~~~\times\frac{\left(1+B^{2}\right)\left(1+A^{2}x^{2}\right)}{\left(B^{2}-A^{2}x^{2}\right)}\cdot\frac{\left(1+A^{2}x^{2}\right)}{2\sqrt{A^{2}x^{2}}}\ln{\left(\frac{1-A^{4}x^{2}}{A^{2}-A^{2}x^{2}}\right)};~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{\frac{(1+a)(1-u)}{(1-a)(1+u)}}=x\right]}\\
&=12\mathcal{J}_{4}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)\mathcal{J}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)b^{2}\mathcal{J}_{0}{\left(a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(2a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}-3b^{4}\right)\\
&~~~~~\times\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2A\left(1+B^{2}\right)^{2}\left(1+A^{2}x^{2}\right)}{\left(1-A^{2}B^{2}x^{2}\right)\left(B^{2}-A^{2}x^{2}\right)}\ln{\left(\frac{1-A^{4}x^{2}}{A^{2}-A^{2}x^{2}}\right)}\\
&=12\mathcal{J}_{4}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)\mathcal{J}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)b^{2}\mathcal{J}_{0}{\left(a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(2a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}-3b^{4}\right)\\
&~~~~~\times\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{\left(1+B^{2}\right)^{2}}{\left(1-B^{2}\right)B}\left[\frac{2AB}{\left(B^{2}-A^{2}x^{2}\right)}-\frac{2AB}{\left(1-A^{2}B^{2}x^{2}\right)}\right]\ln{\left(\frac{1-A^{4}x^{2}}{A^{2}-A^{2}x^{2}}\right)}\\
&=12\mathcal{J}_{4}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)\mathcal{J}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)b^{2}\mathcal{J}_{0}{\left(a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(2a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}-3b^{4}\right)}{b\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{2q}{1-q^{2}x^{2}}-\frac{2p}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}\right]\ln{\left(\frac{1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}}{pq-pqx^{2}}\right)}\\
&=12\mathcal{J}_{4}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)\mathcal{J}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)b^{2}\mathcal{J}_{0}{\left(a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(2a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}-3b^{4}\right)}{b\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{2p}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}-\frac{2q}{1-q^{2}x^{2}}\right]\ln{\left(\frac{pq-pqx^{2}}{1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}}\right)}\\
&=12\mathcal{J}_{4}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)\mathcal{J}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)b^{2}\mathcal{J}_{0}{\left(a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(2a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}-3b^{4}\right)}{b\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\left[\frac{2p}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}-\frac{2q}{1-q^{2}x^{2}}\right]\bigg{[}\ln{\left(pq\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\ln{\left(1-x^{2}\right)}-\ln{\left(1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=12\mathcal{J}_{4}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)\mathcal{J}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)b^{2}\mathcal{J}_{0}{\left(a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(2a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}-3b^{4}\right)}{b\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}\bigg{[}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2p\ln{\left(pq\right)}}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2q\ln{\left(pq\right)}}{1-q^{2}x^{2}}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2p\ln{\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2q\ln{\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}{1-q^{2}x^{2}}\\
&~~~~~-\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2p\ln{\left(1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}\right)}}{1-p^{2}x^{2}}+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{2q\ln{\left(1-p^{2}q^{2}x^{2}\right)}}{1-q^{2}x^{2}}\bigg{]},\\
\end{align}$$

and then,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}{\left(a,b\right)}
&=12\mathcal{J}_{4}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)\mathcal{J}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)b^{2}\mathcal{J}_{0}{\left(a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(2a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}-3b^{4}\right)}{b\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}\bigg{[}2\ln{\left(pq\right)}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(p\right)}-2\ln{\left(pq\right)}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(q\right)}\\
&~~~~~+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+1}{p-1}\right)}-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p}{p+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-1}{p+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q}{q-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+1}{q-1}\right)}+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q}{q+1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-1}{q+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-pq}{p-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+pq}{p-1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p}{p+1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+pq}{p+1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-pq}{p+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q}{q-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-pq}{q-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+pq}{q-1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-2\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q}{q+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+pq}{q+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-pq}{q+1}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=12\mathcal{J}_{4}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)\mathcal{J}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-4\left(5a^{2}-3b^{2}\right)b^{2}\mathcal{J}_{0}{\left(a\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2\left(a^{2}-b^{2}\right)\left(2a^{4}+2a^{2}b^{2}-3b^{4}\right)}{b\sqrt{1-b^{2}}}\bigg{[}-2\ln{\left(pq\right)}\operatorname{artanh}{\left(\frac{q-p}{1-pq}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+1}{p-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-1}{p+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+1}{q-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-1}{q+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-pq}{p-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+pq}{p-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p+pq}{p+1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{p-pq}{p+1}\right)}\\
&~~~~~-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-pq}{q-1}\right)}-\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+pq}{q-1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q+pq}{q+1}\right)}+\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(\frac{q-pq}{q+1}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
\end{align}$$

The case of equal parameters can be found be taking the limit of the expression above, which yields

$$\mathcal{F}{\left(a,a\right)}=\lim_{b\to a}\mathcal{F}{\left(a,b\right)}=12\mathcal{J}_{4}{\left(a\right)}-8a^{2}\mathcal{J}_{2}{\left(a\right)}-8a^{4}\mathcal{J}_{0}{\left(a\right)}.$$

---

*Continued in Part 2...*